# OneSignal Push Notification Failed when user kill the application

Tags: android, onesignal

I have implemented push notification with OneSingal APIs in my android project. I'm facing an issue while clicking the push notification, that i was unable to launch the specified screen when the user click the push notification, If the user kill the app from background(long press and remove the pplication from list of apps). I have registered the Open/Receiver handlers in application class. Seems like, the handlers are no more visible in the app, when user kill/remove the app from background.

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Android apps are not able to receive notifications when they have been force-closed. This is part of the design of the Android OS.

Comment: Then how come WhatsApp notification are working? Even if we remove the app from background, still we can open the notification and navigates to particular screen right? Please help

Comment: @Ravi WhatsApp is sometimes installed as a system-level app which allows it to bypass this limitation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32395912/whatsapp-service-restarts-after-force-stop-when-push-notification-received